# Detecting Different Distributions in data

Tags: clustering, statistics, distribution

Supposing I have a dataset that I assume that have instances generated by two different distributions, is it possible to separate these instances based on the underlying generating distribution?

Also, if I relax this hypothesis, and suppose I know one of the distributions beforehand, is this task possible? The second distribution could he chaotic, and also it is impossible to know it.

Finally, is there any result concerning the distance between the two distributions? Is there any theoretical proof of correctness, if there are algorithms for realizing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really feasible to label points as coming from distribution A or B if there is be overlap amongst the distributions. You can't know whether the point fell near the mean of A or the tail of B. In the simplest case, consider two normally distributed datasets with overlap - how can you know which generated it?

You *could* estimate the probability of each point falling under A or B, but that doesn't really solve the problem.

A different approach, but one I'm not sure will help, would be to fit a new distribution defined as the convolution of A and B. The ex-gaussian distribution is one such example. But you'd have to do the maths to figure out the PDF equation, and that still won't necessarily label your points.

Comment: but by estimating the probability of each point falling under A or B, you could get a good guess for whether it belongs to A or B

Comment: @Thijs Steel That is very true, but for that you need to know the distributions A and B, which is exactly the point in the problem here.

Comment: @tutifresh Ah, i misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a measure of difference between two probability distributions. In that case, if you have two continuous distributions, try measuring the KL divergence ([more information is available here](https://www.countbayesie.com/blog/2017/5/9/kullback-leibler-divergence-explained)). You may also be interested in a chi-squared test, depending on your application (have a look at [Glen_b's answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88764/test-for-difference-between-2-empirical-discrete-distributions)).

I don't think there are any theoretical proofs of correctness. All you can really do is compare your empirical distribution (your instances) to your theoretical distribution (the distribution you know they came from). Sometimes there's going to be a good chance that an instance that came from one distribution looks very much like an instance from another distribution - the instances would not be 'identifiable'. For example, if I'm generating data from a binomial distribution with large n and small p, those instances are going to look like they come from a Poisson distribution ([see more detail here](http://courses.wcupa.edu/rbove/Berenson/10th%20ed%20CD-ROM%20topics/section5_6.pdf)). In that case, the instances themselves are not really distinguishable.

** MAJOR EDIT **

So I misunderstood the question, as you can see from the comments below. If you have one distribution that is made up of two underlying distributions, and you want to label them, I think clustering may be the best way to go. Try something like the k-means algorithm. I'm pretty sure that doesn't require any distributional assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Although, I meant that I have only one single dataset, and the distribution of the dataset is $\mathcal{D} = \pi * \mathcal{D}_1 + (1-\pi) * \mathcal{D}_2$, where $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$ are the two underlying distributions. The thing is, I want to split it into two smaller datasets, $S_1$ and $S_2$, such that $S_1$ is generated by $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $S_2$ is generated by $\mathcal{D}_2$. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I clearly misunderstood the question. Now I'm torn - do I take down my answer? Do I leave it, in case it helps someone else?

Comment: I think you may keep it, it might help someone in need. Do you have any idea of solution for my problem? I was thinking about a clustering algorithm, such as EM, but for EM you need to know the family of the distributions (like GMM/Binomial MM etc.)

Comment: Hi again, have a look at my updated answer? In case it doesn't help, please edit your question to include the information from your comment (pi, D, etc), as I think it will help others answer.

Comment: I think that using an algorithm such as k-means, based on "distance" between instances rather than statistical properties, for classifying them on the specified criteria (different distributions), is not entirely correct. Am I wrong?